# Banking apps disabled in Android SDK emulator

Tags: applications, security, android-emulator

Does the Android SDK emulator run apps with `FLAG_SECURE` used from Android 12? I have been trying to run different banking apps, which work but crash when I get to the login screen which is flagged with the recent security options.

Comment: Usually banking apps are limited to physical device, emulated devices are not accepted as they have a higher chance of being insecure as they run on an unknown host system which can in general access anything within the emulator.  But that has nothing to to with `FLAG_SECURE`. This flag only disables screen shots for an activity.